# Google chrome printing issue screws up text

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have been stressing with this issue all day and can't seem to figure out whats triggering this issue. When I try to print this page with Google Chrome, the styling gets messed up. I include a custom print styling and everything works great on other browsers like Firefox and IE. But when it comes to chrome, this is what happens.

[image: chrome]

please help. for my sanity. print css debugging is no fun.

Comment: Can you post your CSS code?  Does it happen if you change the printer driver or use Chrome's Save as PDF option?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue on Chrome v80 running on macOS Catalina.

After some trial & error I've observed the `BlinkMacSystemFont` included in the font family.

Removing this font from the `font-family` values solved the issue.
It seems like there is some issue in chrome thats causing problem with this font in the print preview rendering.

BTW Safari's print preview works well with `BlinkMacSystemFont` font, its just the chrome thats causing issues with this font.